# Installing GraphLab creates makes my Jupyter Notebook degrade from Python 3.6 to Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I have Python 3.6 installed on my windows computer. I just installed GraphLab Create and now when I open up my Jupyter Notebooks, it shows Python 2 instead of Python 3 which it always was before. How do I go about changing it back to Python 3 in the easiest possible way? Thank you

Comment: Please specify which operating system you are using.

Comment: It is a 64-bit operating system with 16GB Windows. I used Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook every single day and then I created GraphLab create (that's the only change I made I can think of) and now when I opened up any of my jupyter files, it says Python 2. Any ideas?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, you are a genius:) Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @desertnaut, you helped me out a lot recently, do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphLab Create only works in python-2.x. If you did use the GraphlabCreate.exe to install GraphLab, the .exe file installs Anaconda containing python 2.7 in your PC. So you have both python 2 and 3 versions in your system. You can find python3 jupyter notebook inside the Scripts folder in the location where you installed Anaconda3

Comment: Inside the scripts folder it seems that I have 4 files, "jupyterlab.bat", "notebook.bat", "notebook-err-6.txt" and "notebook-out-6.txt". So what should I do?

Comment: Do you know, if I reinstall Jupyter Notebook, will it solve my problem?

Comment: Inside Scripts folder inside Anaconda3 , you will have jupyter-notebook.exe file

Comment: try opening jupyter notebook

Comment: ok I got it to work now, thank you! 1 question though, how can I avoid needing to go to windows explorer and opening it from there, and instead just immediately open the terminal and get it to work to save time?

Comment: To open from terminal, you need to add the location to your Windows path variable, else you can create a shortcut of jupyter notebook to your Desktop and open it from your Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct version of python(in this case python3) to your windows PATH variable

[refer this link](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Once you have the PATH variable setup you should be able to start python3 interpreter from the windows command prompt whenever you type `python`

Now when you type `jupyter notebook` from the terminal it should start the python3 kernel by default

Comment: It is showing for both of them that they are "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Hmm. How do you usually start your jupyter notebook?

Comment: i just type "jupyter notebook" in the terminal or access it through opening up Anaconda, either or

Comment: @mkheifetz check the edited answer. you need to first configure your windows path variable so that you are able to start the python interpreter from the command line

Comment: but I don't understand, why do I need to do that if it worked before? I never got rid of it from anywhere, I just installed an extra program, GraphLab Create

Comment: I can't comment on what changed in your system. However based on your answer it seems python3 isnt configured as the default python execution environment on your system. If it was you'd have been able to start the python3 interpreter from your command line

Comment: I don't have administrative privledges to go in there on my computer. Are there other alternatives? The thing is, in order for it to stop working, according to what you are saying, it was supposed to previously have been there and then been deleted. But why would it get deleted if I am just installing another program?

Comment: will me uninstalling the other software help maybe?